# Get results of some std operations in benchmarks

Tags: runtime, benchmarking, no-std

We faced a situation the other day where we needed some result of std operations inside of our benchmarks. Specifically, we were looking to generate key pairs and signatures from types given by [app_crypto!](https://docs.rs/sp-application-crypto/2.0.0-alpha.5/sp_application_crypto/macro.app_crypto.html)(`Pair` and `Signature`). I imagine there are plenty of other use cases for performing operations depending on std though. So I was curious if there is any existing way around this limitation at the moment.

Comment: Could you please share the code or some snippets of it? Maybe the benchmarking code that does not work? There is a sig-verify example [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6b8553511112afd5ae7e8e6877dc2f467850f155/frame/benchmarking/src/baseline.rs#L95).

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, there's no "right" way to do it. Some script outside of the benchmark would have to be run to generate the values. Here's a FRAME [example](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/5cdb054049980eecb449c36a7ccfe4990329c494/frame/babe/src/benchmarking.rs#L80) where primitive types such as keypairs are generated and scale-encoded in the script, and decoded in the benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

> We faced a situation the other day where we needed some result of std operations inside of our benchmarks.

There is two ways this goes:

- It runs in the runtime and is therefore no-std: Use the pallet benchmarking.
- It is std and does not run in the runtime: Use some other benchmarking tools like criterion. However I don't see where this could be needed, since pallet benchmarks cover everything that is normally needed.

> I imagine there are plenty of other use cases for performing operations depending on std though.

No. Since the runtime is entirely no-std and the benchmarks only cover on-chain code.
The only exception is the setup phase, where it would be reasonable to have no-std access for convenience. Otherwise all setup code needs to be no-std as well which is annoying.

> Specifically, we were looking to generate key pairs and signatures from types given by app_crypto!(Pair and Signature).

I don't understand why you generate key-pairs on-chain. These are public for everyone to see.

Comment: Forgot about this issue. I found a pretty good example that I'll link.

To be clear, I'm not generating key-pairs on-chain. I'm not sure why you're suggesting that I was doing that.

Comment: Though I do see the value of posting safe reminders like this on SE, out of abundance of caution 